How to insert a title at the beginning of an edited document?
I have a bunch of existing documents. Problem: they have no title. My idea is to open every document and add the (modified) filename as a title.
I can't find a way to insert a title at the beginning of an existing document. Every command i tried adds the title at the end of the document.
I hope one of you can give me a hint which command and how I can use it.

Can you show the code you've tried which incorrectly adds the title to the end of the doc?

Welcome to Stack Overlow! Please review [ask], and provide a [mre] showing what you have already tried.

You can achieve this by using the insert_paragraph_before method and inserting the title before the first paragraph:
from docx import Document

def insert_title(docx_file, title):
    document = Document(docx_file)

    # Insert the title at the beginning
    document.paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before(title, style='Heading 1')

    document.save(docx_file)

Then you can easily add a title like this:
insert_title('my_document.docx', "Hello, World!")

If you want to add a page break after the title (to have it on a separate page):
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK
from docx import Document

def insert_title(docx_file, title):
    document = Document(docx_file)

    # Insert the title at the beginning
    heading = document.paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before(title, style='Heading 1')

    run = heading.add_run()
    run.add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)

    document.save(docx_file)


Great, thank you. Works perfectly.

According to the documentation, if you want to have a title on just a single doc, the following would work
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

For an n number of documents, you would need to apply loop on the last two lines.

This is probably what he has already tried, and it will add the new heading to the end of the document.

Wow, thanks for your quick answer. But (at least for me) it doesn't work. It ends the tile at the end.
